# Freeware that joins many .html files into one?

Tags: windows, gratis, html

Is there a free software that joins many `.html` files into one?

It should be on Windows and should strip only the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Simple File Joiner](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/sfj.html):

- free
- Windows
- GUI
- merge HTML files:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With Cygwin you could use this [Bash script](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/merge-of-html-files-into-a-single-html-or-pdf-284545/):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter directory path pages:";
read html_path;
echo "Enter complete filename of the starting page:"
read start_page;
ls $html_path > "list.txt";
grep -iv "</body>" "$html_path/$start_page" | grep -iv "</html>" > "$html_path/all_merged.html";
for i in $(< list.txt)
do
    grep -iv "<body>" "$html_path/$i" | grep -iv "<html>" | grep -iv "</body>" | grep -iv "</html>" >> "$html_path/all_merged.html"
done
echo "</body></html>" >> "$html_path/all_merged.html"
echo "Merged file ---> $html_path/all_merged.html"
unset html_path;
unset start_page;
unset i;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [SoftSnow Merger](http://softsnow.griffin3.com/merger/merger.shtml)  which support what I need :

> "Strip header/footer" option strips redundant style sheets, Javascript
>   blocks, HEAD and HTML tags from the files.

Also [VirusTotal doesn't found only one hit which seem to be a false positive.](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5a08021570f79062777671b75ae1221ec9c44f6c9b6b4f1a1256284f8ba8299e/analysis/1404452486/)